# Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.0 install script

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ftp, bcrypt

I am getting this error when I run 'npm install' on the Ubuntu server in my current project.
I tried installing 'bcryptjs', still getting the same error.

````
node-pre-gyp ERR! install error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: The N-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module supports N-API version(s) 3. This Node instance cannot run this module.
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.validate_package_json (/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/napi.js:82:9)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at validate_config (/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js:229:10)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.evaluate (/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js:279:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at install (/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js:241:31)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js:52:37)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at run (/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp:82:30)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp:134:1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-101-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/mission_education/ftp/files/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
The N-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module supports N-API version(s) 3. This Node instance cannot run this module.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-07-14T12_11_05_809Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620327/the-n-api-version-of-this-node-instance-is-1-this-module-supports-n-api-version

Comment: @MarkAdel I can't update the node/npm globally please suggest me something else.

Comment: I don't know why can't you update your node version, but in this case you can install the bcrypt version that is compatible with your node version, you can find a version compatibility table in the package's readme on github.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Node.JS because you have N-API version 1 and you need version 3 at least as stated here:

`stack Error: The N-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module supports N-API version(s) 3. This Node instance cannot run this module.`