# Issues installing Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sequelize.js, backend

I am finishing some backend tutorials and when i tried to install Sequelize with Node this is what it displays on the screen i have tried to downgrade the versions of Node js to solve the problem and updated other dependencies but it doesnt work, i am currently using 8.4.0 Node version, the one that is used on the tutorial and the lesson but it doesnt fix the issue, hope you can help me with this so i can move on to finish my course and do the exam, here it is what i get after trying to install:

P.D. I am working on a OS Windows 10 desktop computer.

```
C:\Users\AIO 330-20AST\Desktop\backend\base_datos> node server.js
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for N-API version 3
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for N-API version 6
C:\Users\AIO 330-20AST\Desktop\backend\base_datos\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\napi.js:84
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: The N-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module
supports N-API version(s) 3,6. This Node instance cannot run this
module.
    at Object.module.exports.validate_package_json (C:\Users\AIO
330-20AST\Desktop\backend\base_datos\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\napi.js:84:9)
    at Object.validate_config (C:\Users\AIO
330-20AST\Desktop\backend\base_datos\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\versioning.js:229:10)
    at Object.exports.find (C:\Users\AIO
330-20AST\Desktop\backend\base_datos\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\pre-binding.js:21:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AIO
330-20AST\Desktop\backend\base_datos\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)

C:\Users\AIO 330-20AST\Desktop\backend\base_datos>
```

For your help thanks in advance, good coding!

Comment: I'd first try installing at least the LTS version of node (currently 14.16.0 LTS). Node 8 is quite a few years old now nearly 4 years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The N-API version of this Node instance is 1. This module supports N-API version(s) 3. This Node instance cannot run this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620327/the-n-api-version-of-this-node-instance-is-1-this-module-supports-n-api-version)

Comment: Thank you for your input i have upgraded Node to latest version i may have figured out the solution based on the warnings i get now, it might be an issue on the database since i completed that excersice with a lower version of Node i need to redo it and run it again ill post the results, thanks again good luck!